# Runtime exception in magento 2 installation on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, magento2, magento2.1

I am trying below command to install magento 2.1 on ubuntu (Nginx and PHP 5.6) but i am getting a runtime exception with message

`[Runtime Exception] "-?" option does not exist`.

```
php bin/magento setup:install -–base-url=<my_ip> --backend-frontname=admin 
--db-host=<my_host> --db-name=magento2 --db-user=root --db-password=<my_password> 
--admin-firstname=Subham --admin-lastname=Kumar --admin-email=<my_email> --admin-user=admin 
--admin-password=<m2_password>--language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago –-use-rewrites=1
```

Comment: what is exactly the message? what version of magento? what equipment are you using (db/webserver/php version)? provide more details

Comment: Magento version is 2.1 and i am using nginx with php5.6 on Ubuntu, error message is :  [RuntimeException]
  The "-?" option does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=example.com --db-host= --db-name= --db-user=root --db-password= --admin-firstname= --admin-lastname= --admin-email= --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --backend-frontname=admin_magento --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=Asia/Tbilisi  --use-rewrites=1